# Subplots from two DataFrames in one column, sharing x -axis

Tags: python, pandas

I need to plot few columns (two or more columns per one plot) from two DataFrames in one column,sharing x -axis. All data has the same index.
Example taken and modified from [[1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html)]:

```py
 df = DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), index=date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000), columns=list('AB'))
 df2 = DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), index=df.index, columns=list('CD'))
 df = df.cumsum()
 df2 = df.cumsum()

 fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
 df['A'].plot(ax=axes[0,0])
 df2['C'].plot(ax=axes[0,0])
 df['B'].plot(ax=axes[1,0])
 df2['D'].plot(ax=axes[1,0])
```

Running this I got: `IndexError: too many indices` Is this a bug or do I missing something ?

When I change `ncols=2`,everything is ok, but with two additional blank plots.

I can use other solution but that above looks better:

```py
ax1 = subplot(211)
df['A'].plot()
df2['C'].plot()

ax2 = subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
df['B'].plot()
df2['D'].plot()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `axes` is a 1D ndarray so `axes[0, 0]` is not a valid index. Only 0 and 1 are valid. Change the plotting code to:

```
df['A'].plot(ax=axes[0])
df2['C'].plot(ax=axes[0])
df['B'].plot(ax=axes[1])
df2['D'].plot(ax=axes[1])
```

You could also do

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

df['A'].plot(ax=ax1)
df2['C'].plot(ax=ax1)
df['B'].plot(ax=ax2)
df2['D'].plot(ax=ax2)
```

Comment: I don't want to comment  my question. It was so obvious...Thank you @PhilipCloud once again and sorry for making you trouble.